# Accessing .ENV Properties with Angular2 Typescript and ServerJS

Tags: swift, node.js, typescript, angular, npm

I've been going through the Angular2 Quickstart and tutorials and now I'm trying to get set up pulling data from a live REST Api. I need to pass in authentication parameters with the Api call and everything I'm reading says I should be putting those parameters into the ENV variables.

I can't work out exactly how I should be doing this. I've created a .env file on my local server, I've used NPM to instal dotenv to my project, but none of the examples I can find for how to use dotenv seem to fit with the TypeScript import syntax I'm used to.

Here's my main.ts:

```
import { }              from 'dotenv/config';
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

And a sample app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Up and running!</h1>
    <p>Do not show this at home: {{process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY}}</p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['style.css']
})

export class AppComponent { 

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've been out of the coding loop for a while and this is all a bit new to me.

Bonus question, would I still have the .env file when I go to a live server or does it change?

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: Haven't given @Mrinal's answer a try yet. Been focused elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to initialize the dotenv config method:

```
dotenv.config();
```

I usually use as follow:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

//Later in your code
dotenv.config();
```

Then you may use your environment variables.

Comment: Still, cannot find `dotenv`, although it is installed.

Comment: @frankfullstack  Do they have support for angular 2 onwards if, then how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Couldn't find a proper solution so I did something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Up and running!</h1>
    <p>Do not show this at home: {{twitterConsumerKey}}</p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['style.css']
})

export class AppComponent { 

  public twitterConsumerKey:string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.twitterConsumerKey = process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY;
  }
}
```